# Syncing with SQLite database and Android Calendar

Tags: android, sqlite, calendar, synchronization

I have a rather complex question regarding syncing data between my application's `SQLite` database, a user's `Calendar`s, and a webserver.

This is essentially the behavior I  need:

`onResume()`: **Any modified `Event`s on any `Calendar` on any `Account` result in an update in my application's `SQLite` database.** (only `Account`'s the user specifies, of course).

What I'm doing write now is updating every entry in my `SQLite` database with each `Calendar` event, whether it's been updated or not in `onResume()`. This is, of course, not ideal.

I'm already able to pull all events into my application's `SQLite` database, and sync between my database and my webserver. The main issue is syncing between my `SQLite` database and the `Calendar`. From [my research](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events.html), I've read that you can only write to the `DIRTY` flag on a Calendar if you implement your own `SyncAdapter`. This would also require me to implement a `ContentProvider`, which I would like to avoid. So my questions are:

1. Is there any reliable method for seeing modified `Calendar` events without implementing a SyncAdapter?
2. If  not, is it garaunteed that I'll be able to maintain my own `DIRTY` flag for my application? I know Google uses the `DIRTY` flag to sync `Calendar`s with Google Calendar. If Google Calendar were to continuously set and reset this flag, it would not help me maintain my application.
3. Is there a recommended design approach for this type of problem that I'm otherwise oblivious to? Such as another method to keep a "last_modified" type flag for each `Calendar Event`?

Cheers.

**Edit:** I should also add that I'm targetting Android 4.0+ with the application now, but I would like to support all versions in the future.

Comment: I've run into issues with calendar calls on earlier android versions. For example, many HTC devices fail with calls that work fine on other brands/versions. If you can get away with not using the calendar directly (not via an intent) in pre 4, do it.

Comment: Thank you, but this functionality is integral to the application.

Comment: Just a quick question - why would you need to implement a `ContentProvider` of your own for your `SyncAdapter` - it's not required as a part of the account & sync adapter API.

Comment: From my understanding it's required to Sync with. Unless you mean just fill in a dummy ContentProvider?